# How to do an .append loop in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing out text labels to my svg in multiple lines. The solution I have is working and ok, but it has a limitation that it will not draw any more lines than what I hard-code, and also there is a bit of inefficient processing. Is there a better way to make this happen, without having to re-parse the name string every time, and appending the tspan just the right amount of times?

```
node.append("text")
.attr("id", function(d){ return "contact-node-label-"+d.id })
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("dy", function(d)
{
    // split name by space and -
    var n = d.name.replace("-","- ").split(" ") // this expression is repeated
    return n.length/3-(n.length-1)*0.9+'em'
})
.text(function(d)
{
    var n = d.name.replace("-","- ").split(" ")
    // return first part of name
    return n[0]
})
// some kind of loop would start here
.append("tspan").attr('x',0).attr('dy','1em').text(function(d)
{
    var n = d.name.replace("-","- ").split(" ");
    if (n.length > 1) return n[1];
})
// second round of loop would be this
.append("tspan").attr('x',0).attr('dy','1em').text(function(d)
{
    var n = d.name.replace("-","- ").split(" ");
    if (n.length > 2) return n[2];
})
```

Perhaps I could use the following code. The problem is that n is created (and recreated) inside the method, and if I save it outside it will reference the wrong data. The solution would be to be able to put this code inside one of the methods, but I couldn't make it work (neither in the text method, nor in the tspan append method):

```
d3.select(this).append("tspan").attr('x',0).attr('dy','1em').text( n[i] )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`.each`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each):

```
node.append("text")
    .each(function(d) {
        // split name by space and -
        var n = d.name.replace("-","- ").split(" ");
        // get the current element
        var text = d3.select(this)
            .attr("dy", n.length / 3 - (n.length-1) * 0.9 + 'em')
            .text(n[0]);
        // now loop
        for (var i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
            text.append("tspan")
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('dy', '1em')
                .text(n[i])
        }
    });
```

One big advantage of `.each`, as shown here, is that it gives you a per-element scope to work with, making it easy to avoid repeated calculations like this.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. Thanks! By the way, are you using the offset and firstPart variables?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, had them as variables before inlining them in the `.attr` calls.